# Align <div>'s to the right of an image

Tags: css, drupal

I am stuck with some CSS.
I need this:

[image]

But I have this (applying `float:left` to the image):

[image]

The HTML is generated by Drupal so I can't change its structure:

```
<div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="field field-name-field-gallery-work-order field-type-image field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.gcca.eu/sites/default/files/styles/stories-field-thumb/public/ACP/workorders/rwanda_photo_2_land_registration_programme_gcca_eud.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="field field-name-field-country-media field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-inline clearfix"><div class="field-label">Country:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Madagascar</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field field-name-field-region field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Region:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Africa</div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

And I have the folloing styles set to the image:

```
.node-work-order .field-type-image img {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
}

.field-type-image img {
    background: #F3F0E8;
    border: 1px solid #DAC5B4;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

How can I align the region and other attributes under Country and to the right of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a `float:left` on the image container, not on the image:

```
.field-type-image{
    float:left;
}    

 .field-label-inline{
    margin-left: 280px; /* width of the image */
}
```

Or if the width of the image varies, you can keep the content aligned with a hidden overflow:

```
.field-type-image{
    float:left;
}    

.field-label-inline{
    overflow:hidden;    
}
```

Comment: @AndreaLigios No, you shouldn't always put a fiddle. This code is far too simple to warrant a jsfiddle. There's no point using it just for the sake of it

Comment: It will help you to get more votes thanks to the immediate feedback coming from the testability. You should add it to the answer, not in the comments :)

Comment: @Clive: no need for the OP, but a little advantage for readers who must set up the code to test themselves. 1 min economized, 1 min earned...

Comment: @AndreaLigios Getting votes should not be the goal of answering a question, that's a bad attitude to have for Stack Exchange sites. 'Rep whoring' as it's more frequently known is a problem that needs to go away, not be encouraged. But anyway that wasn't my point. My point is that your suggestion that "you should (always) put a fiddle" is incorrect. Where appropriate, sure, but not for something as trivial as this. If the OP _wishes_ to add one in, fine, but there's no need to prompt people to do so

Comment: @Clive: neither the goal should be *not* getting votes ;) I've got your point and agree with you on the fact that the code posted is not hard to test, I won't evangelize *fiddling* for minimal answers anymore... but my suggestion had nothing to do with *rep whoring*, it was only to help providing more immediate (and easily votable, that is not a bad thing, until it's not the main objective in your life) answers. Cheers ! :)

Comment: I didn't mean that to sound like an accusation, it wasn't mean to be :)

Answer (score 0):

The second div is clearing the float, that's why it stays down. You could nullify the clearfix like so:

```
.field-name-field-region.field-type-list-text.field-label-inline{
    clear:none
}
```